# Object Reference by a constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, class, object, stack

As we read that, when an object is created for a class like `MyClass myClass = new MyClass();`  then the instance will be created and the reference pointer will be stored in the stack memory. If the class doesn't have a constructor, then a default constructor will be called, then say the default constructor will return the pointer. Take a case where the class has a non-parametarized constructor, then no reference will be returned from my constructor. Then from where will the pointer for the reference be returned and how will that be created.

Comment: That's not a very accurate description. If a class doesn't have a constructor, it can't be instantiated. If you don't *define* one as part of the class definition, the compiler will *generate* an empty default one for you (but it's possible for some classes not to have *any* constructors, e.g. static classes). The constructor doesn't actually return the *reference*. Constructors don't have a return type (they're implicitly void). The runtime is what allocates the object, calls the constructor, and returns the reference after the constructor returns.

Comment: @madreflection where will that reference comes from? Because Constructor is the entry point of the Class. Probably that should create the reference.

Comment: No, the `newobj` IL instruction does that. It calls into the runtime to allocate memory on the managed heap. **It** then calls the constructor. `newobj` takes a metadata token that identifies which constructor to use, so it knows what to call once the memory has been allocated.

Comment: I have read that a few times, and can't work out what the **question** is. I _think_ it is in the last sentence but it is quite hard to parse.

Comment: @mjwills: It's my hope that in straightening out OP's understanding of the earlier points that a better question can be formulated. I, too, am uncertain what the question is but it was predicated on inaccurate statements so it's moot, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: all constructors return the object which has been constructed.

> If the class doesn't have a constructor, then a default constructor
>   will be called, then say the default constructor will return the
>   pointer.

You are right. However what you call a "default constructor" is actually a **parameterless constructor** such as `public MyClass()`. And the compiler does generates one **by default** if the programmer didn't write one.

> Take a case where the class has a non-parametarized constructor, then
>   no reference will be returned from my constructor.

If by "non-parametarized constructor" you mean a constructor with one or more parameters such as `public MyClass(int arg)`, then the compiler will not generate a parameterless constructor by default. However the compiler will ensure you are calling only the constructors that have been defined.

Comment: Non parameterized constructor is a constructor with zero parameters

Comment: I've always read a parameterless constructor. Anyway we speak about the same thing. Now can you tell me what you want to know more about constructors, because I think my answer says the fundamentals of them. Or maybe I am missing something

Answer (score 1):

The pointer doesn't come from the constructor. Creation of the object and executing the constructor are two different actions.

The C# language specification (1.6.7.1) states:

> An instance constructor is a member that implements the actions
>   required to initialize an instance of a class

Consequently, the constructor doesn't create the object. Instead it initializes the memory associated with the object. In the simple example below, the creation is handled by `CORINFO_HELP_NEWFAST`, but that's just one of several ways to create an object as pointed out by the post linked below.

To illustrate take a simple program like this.

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var p = new Program();
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(p.GetType());
    }

    public Program() {
        Console.WriteLine("ctor");
    }
}
```

Which compiles to the following code.

```
00760848 55              push    ebp
00760849 8bec            mov     ebp,esp
0076084b 56              push    esi
0076084c b9504d7100      mov     ecx,714D50h (MT: ConsoleApp3.Program)
00760851 e87228faff      call    007030c8 (JitHelp: CORINFO_HELP_NEWSFAST)
00760856 8bf0            mov     esi,eax
00760858 8bce            mov     ecx,esi
0076085a ff15704d7100    call    dword ptr ds:[714D70h] (ConsoleApp3.Program..ctor(),     mdToken: 06000002)
00760860 e82bf32973      call    mscorlib_ni+0xb8fb90 (739ffb90)     (System.Console.ReadLine(), mdToken: 06000b6a)
00760865 8bce            mov     ecx,esi
00760867 e8d0f8ffff      call    0076013c (System.Object.GetType(), mdToken: 0600022e)
0076086c 8bc8            mov     ecx,eax
0076086e e88d1ead72      call    mscorlib_ni+0x3c2700 (73232700)     (System.Console.WriteLine(System.Object), mdToken: 06000b77)
00760873 5e              pop     esi
00760874 5d              pop     ebp
00760875 c3              ret
```

Notice that the first action is the call to `CORINFO_HELP_NEWFAST` which creates the object.

This is followed by the call to the constructor which initializes the object, but at that point the object has been allocated and we have a pointer to it. The constructor doesn't *create* the instance, it *initializes* it.

More details on this from Vance Morrison [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vancem/digging-deeper-into-managed-code-with-visual-studio-using-sos).

Comment: Yes! That's what I'm talkin' about.